# Reset Variable with if/then statement

Tags: objective-c, reset

I am trying to reset a variable when it reaches the value 60. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
if [secondTick isEqualto: 60] {
    int secondTick = 0;
}
```

What's wrong?

EDIT:

Here' show I created secondTick:

```
int secondTick =0;
```

Comment: What language is this?  Please tag your question

Comment: @shf301 I am working in objective-c and have tagged appropriately.

Comment: OP showed in various comments to the answers that he is missing the very fundamentals of C, Objective-C and OOP. There-for I vote for closure for not demonstrating the minimal understanding of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining the variable, so it is not necessary, you can just use like below:

if (secondTick == 60)
      secondTick = 0;

Comment: This brings up the error saying that it needs an identifier.

Comment: Even if it is necessary, you should declare it before the if statement, but it is still weird though.

Comment: What would it look like to fix this?

Comment: It might be like:
int secondTick;

if [secondTick isEqualto: 60] {
    secondTick = 0;
}

Otherwise, you will have two different variables which are named same but they will have different memory address to keep the data.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to have a look at this page to have a better understanding:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class

Comment: Part of the issue here may be that `secondTick` is being used as both an object (-isEqualTo: is being called on it) and a primitive (an integer is being assigned to it). I think the OP needs to figure out which it really is and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot compare int values (they are not objects) with `isEqualTo:` as it requires objects on both sides (left hand side must always be an object, as you can only send messages to objects).

If you don't understand what I am talking about you should start over with a basic Objective-C tutorial.

---

Mehmet showed you how to do simple int comparison. But as we have no clue what secondTick is, it might be an object.

If it is an NSNumber object, you would do something like:

```
if([secondTick isEqualToNumber:@60]){
    secondTick = @0;
}
          //                    ^-------------- a nsnumber literal. same as [NSNumber numberWithInteger:60];
          //      ^-------------- same as [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];
```

---

assuming `secondTick` is a plain int, you also could do

```
secondTick = (secondTick + 1) % 60;
```

`%` is the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). It returns the rest of a integer division.

Comment: How would you rewrite the code to do what I would like it to do?

Comment: you didn't give us enough information to answer it for sure. either mehmet's code is the right one or mine.

Comment: To clarify, secondTick is simply a variable that I am displaying as a label on a view controller. It is being increased every second, and I want it to reset when it gets to 60 seconds.

Comment: this doesn't explain anything. a variable is just a name. it can either address an object or an primitive time. you should post the code how you create it.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: you should also include the context. is the declaration within the same method as the other code?

Comment: Yes. All the code is within the same .m file.

Comment: ok, seriously: start over with learning. I ask for the method, not the class. and a class is not the *m-file*. where is `secondTick` defined?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Your `if` statement is incorrect. `isEqualToNumber:` returns a `BOOL`. You seem to be thinking of the `compare:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks. anyway, we found out that we are dealing with ints.  And that there is a scope issue.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I tried to use your second method, and it says that it is a redefinition of 'secondTick'. How would I fix this issue?

Comment: man, this is what i try to explain you for one hour now: tell us the scope of your variable! is it a member? and you would fix it be NOT redefining it. if you don't understand what I am saying: sorry — but you didn't get the very basic things. and this site is not a online teaching platform. I can't teach you C, Objective-C and object orientated programming here.